# Can i use .so file from Apk and use in a python / Java Script

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, .so, android-native-library

I have an apk. one **.so** file is being used in this apk.
There is a function in the .so file. APK is invoking that function by passing 4 inputs as a parameter and getting output.

Now I have to call that function from python or java and want the output which is given in return

so how can do it and is it possible to do something link that?

Comment: so files can be called using JNI on Java. You can check the Java Native Interface for for more details. Also add the library that you are using there is a good chance if it is a common library that somebody might have already used on Java

Comment: what about the android dependencies? if let's suppose it has then also we will use it externally ?

Comment: The so are generally standalone they do not have any external android specific dependencies they are only dependent on the target CPU they are compiled for so X86 so will only work on a 32bit cpu X64 on 64 bit etc as I said the exact details can only be known based on what library you are targeting